# How to check number of common values betweeon two columns from different files

Tags: shell

Suppose I have two files

```
$A
a b
1 5 
2 6
3 7
4 8

$B
a b
1 5 
2 6
5 6
```

My question is, in Shell or Terminal, How to calculate the total number of values of B's first column (1,2,5) in the A's first column(1,2,3,4)? (here the answer is 2 (1,2).

Comment: Compare just first column or ensure second column value matches as well?

Comment: Just sum up how many values of B$a in A$a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `awk` solution counts column1 entries of file2 in file1:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$b;next}$1 in a{count++}END{print count}' file1 file2
2
```

- Skip the first line from both files using `FNR==1{next}`. You can remove this if you don't have header fields (`a b`) in your actual data files.
- Read the entire first file into an array using `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$b;next}`. I am assigning column2 here if you wish to scale the solution to match both columns. You can also do `a[$1]++` if you are not interested in column2 at all. Wont hurt either ways.
- If the value of column1 from second file is in our array, increment a count variable
- In the `END` block print the count variable.

Comment: Great helpful! Thanks, jaypal.